# Unable to Install Gimp on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, apt, gimp

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and tried to install GIMP.

First, i try to install via Ubuntu Software Center
and here's the result

[image]

Then i tried to install via terminal and here's the output.

```
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.2-0 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$
```

Then i try to install the dependencies manually

```
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install libgegl-0.2-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgegl-0.2-0 : Depends: libumfpack5.6.2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install libumfpack5.6.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libumfpack5.6.2 : Depends: libcholmod2.1.2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install libcholmod2.1.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcholmod2.1.2 : Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                            liblapack.so.3
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install liblapack3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblapack3 : Depends: libgfortran3 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) but 4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-4.8-base is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3'
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-4.8.5-2ubuntu1~14.04.1'
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$
```

After that, i try to install with PPA

```
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
 This PPA is for Ubuntu >=12.04 and Linux Mint >=13

Installing: 
open a terminal and type:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp

Removing:
open a terminal and type:
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp 

Many thanks to David Tschumperlé for his masterpiece called G'MIC. 
http://gmic.eu/
Look for the gmic packages!

We should not forget the Gimp crew!
http://www.gimp.org/

And many, many thanks to http://siduction.org. They helped me on my first steps making the Gimp packages.

I promise as long as I live this PPA will never die and the most recent packages will for ever be. ;-)

Regards

Otto Meier

If you had a really problem: 
Skype: thorsten.stettin
G+: https://plus.google.com/u/0/117581776478455814502/posts
FB: https://www.facebook.com/otto06217

Some stats:

http://kesselgulasch.org/ppastats/gimp/

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp2rcqjr64/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp2rcqjr64/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 614C4B38 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmp2rcqjr64/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 614C4B38: public key "Launchpad otto06217" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt update
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65,9 kB]             
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release                                
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease [15,4 kB]                      
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://archive.canonical.com trusty/partner Translation-en                 
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [395 kB]           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [6.327 B]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [176 kB]       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [7.763 B]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [972 kB]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages [7.633 B]            
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages [7.646 B]             
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en [7.388 B]           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [17,1 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [402 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14,3 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [932 kB]    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US               
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en                  
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [16,9 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [403 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14,6 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                    
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US                
Fetched 3.461 kB in 28s (120 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$ sudo apt install gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.2-0 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
dontus@n0cturn4L-PC:~$
```

I've also tried to change the "Download From" to Main server, Server from US, my closest mirror, and other mirror then retry the step with PPA but it didn't work.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Dontus

Comment: Try to install it using this http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gimp/gimp_2.8.10-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb

Comment: First [remove all external PPA](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed),then do a `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`  and post the output if any error occurs.

Comment: @M.Becerra i tried to install with the deb package via Ubuntu Software Center and via terminal but it didnt work

Comment: @g_p the i did the instruction you have provided, and these error occured `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.8.10-z) but 2.8.20-0t0~ppa is to be installed
        Depends: gimp-data (<= 2.8.10-z) but 2.8.20-0t0~ppa is to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.2-0 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: `libgimp2.0` is only available from the 16.16 repo, the PPA you added is for 12.04, and you have Ubuntu 14.04...

Comment: Ok, remove `gimp` using `sudo apt-get purge gimp` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove ` and then execute `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: @M.Becerra done guys, all happen is some depedencies conflict with virtualbox depedencies. i did some experience with synaptics and the output from the error. well all i need is using virtualbox-qt depedencies. Thanks for your help :D !

Comment: @g_p done guys, all happen is some depedencies conflict with virtualbox depedencies. i did some experience with synaptics and the output from the error. well all i need is using virtualbox-qt depedencies. thanks for your help :D !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone who experiences the same problem I had, which seems to be caused by having Virtualbox installed from the `.deb` provided on the official website:

Try to use Synaptic Package Manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`) to do the following:

- Remove `libgimp2.0`and `gimp-data`
- Install `libgegl-0.2-0`

Now synaptics will remove some Virtualbox depedencies and install some other depedencies required for gimp.

To get Virtualbox back, you can reinstall it by using `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-qt`.

Special Thanks for [@M. Becerra](https://askubuntu.com/users/605093/m-becerra) and [@g_p](https://askubuntu.com/users/146791/g-p) for giving me some clues that lead me to solve this problem.

Comment: I'ts great that you managed and came back to report your solution :)

Comment: this is my first post on this forum, and i'm bad at descripting 'the-how-to', then also my english is bad. thanks for improving my answer :D